# how to get API response in multiple curly braces?

Tags: magento2, api

I'm trying to API response in multiple curly braces,
but it's not coming.
below is my code.

```
/**
    * @return array
    */
    public function Newdata()
    {   
        //get Customer Order collection by Customer Id and Email Magento 2

        $customerCollection =  $this->_customer->getCollection()
                                               ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                                               ->load();
        $customeid = $customerCollection->getData('customer_id');    
        
        try {
            

            $customerID = $customeid;

            $customerOrder = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', $customerID)->load();

            $finalArray = [];            

            if(!empty($customerOrder->getData())){


                foreach ($customerOrder as $item) {  
                      
                    $finalArray[] = $item->getEntityId();                    
                }
                
               //$finalArray['entity_id'] = $customerOrder->getData();

                $response = ['success' => 200, 'message' => 'Success', 'data' => $finalArray];    
            }else{
                $response = ['success' => 404, 'message' => "Data Not Found", 'data' => []];    
            }
        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            $response = ['success' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage(), 'data' => []];
            $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
        }
        return [$response];
    }
    
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[
    {
        "success": 200,
        "message": "Success",
        "data": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3"
        ]
    }
]
```

but I need like (in curly braces)

```
[
    {
        "success": 200,
        "message": "Success",
        "data": [
            {"1"},
            {"2"},
            {"3"}
        ]
    }
]
```

how can I do that?? please, help me with this,
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

To change the API Response, you need to update the code:

```
foreach ($customerOrder as $item) {  
     
     $finalArray[][] = $item->getEntityId();                    
            
   }

  $response = ['success' => 200, 'message' => 'Success', 'data' => $finalArray];
```

OR

```
 foreach ($customerOrder as $item) {  
     
     $finalArray[$item][] = $item->getEntityId();                    
            
   }

  $response = ['success' => 200, 'message' => 'Success', 'data' => $finalArray];
```

OR

```
 foreach ($customerOrder as $item) {  
     
     $finalArray[] = array($item->getEntityId());                    
            
   }

  $response = ['success' => 200, 'message' => 'Success', 'data' => $finalArray];
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but all the above codes I have tried, do not work as per my requirement.

Comment: Let's discuss this in a personal chat

Comment: ok let's discuss, how can we connect? @Jyotishinha